# How can I add a class on my <tr> row every last day of the month to display months separately?

Tags: php

I have a table in my database with a column called "Creation_date" so every entry has a creation date. In my view, I created a query to display them all in a table so every `<tr>` is a while loop of every entries or row of my database.

I would like to add class name (.last) on a  every last day of a month so like that I can go add a margin-bottom in CSS to separate every month. Now it's all stuck together. Also I need to separate every 3 months for a better presentation, like grouping them.

I'm trying to have a different visual with CSS so I want to group every day of the same month and make a space to group the next month etc.

Can someone help me to think about the logic behind that ?

**Year 2022**

January

- Entry #1
- Entry #2
- Entry #3
  [one br]

February

- Entry #1
- Entry #2
- Entry #3
  [one br]

March

- Entry #1
- Entry #2
- Entry #3
  [two br br]

========

April

- Entry...
  [one br]

May

- Entry...
  [one br]

June

- Entry...
  [two br br]

========

July

- Entry...
  [one br]

August

- Entry...
  [one br]

September

- Entry...
  [two br br]

========

October

- Entry...
  [one br]

November

- Entry...
  [one br]

December

- Entry...
  [two br br]

Thank you

I don't know where to start, I have the month in a variable that's it...

**EDIT:**

Here is an example:

```
<?php
  $query = '
    SELECT
      Project_ID,
      Creation_date,
      DATE_FORMAT(Creation_date, "%m") Creation_date_M,
      Project_name
    FROM Projects
    ORDER BY Creation_date DESC
  ';
  $result = $conn->query($query);
?>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Creation Date</th>
      <th>Project name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
      <?php $month = $row['Creation_date_M']; ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?= $row['Creation_date_full']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['Project_name']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: "In my view, I created a query to display them all". Query logic does not belong in the view. "How can I add a class on my TR row" Where's your TR? Can you show us an example of the HTML generated?

Comment: Have you considered making multiple tables with titles?

Comment: On the last day of the month - or on the last day of that month that you actually got records for?

Comment: @CBroe I edited my post but no I'm trying to have a different visual with CSS so I want to group every date with the same month and make a space to group the next month etc.

Comment: Can we focus on 1 question at a time?

Comment: My question rather was, will the "last" day of January be January 31st - or the last day of January, that you actually have data for (which must not necessarily be the 31st.) But either way, it should not matter much, if you just implement a classic _control break_ here: Compare the month of the current record, with that of the previous one - and depending on whether they are the same, or differ, react accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In css you have a pseudo class called `:last-child` wich allows you to apply css style to the last child. [Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

for example, this will apply a 2px border on the last td of every tr.

```
td:last-child {
    border: 2px solid orange
}
```

you can also use it with classes or any css selector

```
.myClass:last-child {
    border: 2px solid orange
}
```

I am not really sure to understand your code and the result that you have, but I think this example should be enough for you to solve your issue.

Another way of doing this, would be to use `<ul><li>` instead of a table (depends on how you wanna display it), and add your custom css separator on your `ul` element.

Hope this helped

Comment: _"you can also use it with classes or any css selector"_ - well, you can, and you can't. Sure, `.myClass:last-child` is a valid selector - but it will only match if the last child element of the parent also has that class; but this does _not_ select the last element _of the class_.

Comment: Yes, this was an example. My point was it's solvable with the `:last-child` pseudo class. Can't really provide exact answer to question without it's resulting html :/

Comment: The HTML here is just a number of table rows, containing data for _multiple_ months. And the point is _not_ to select just the last one of those, but _all_ of them that represent the "last day" of one of those months. So `:last-child` currently can't help here at all, with the given HTML structure.

Comment: Guess I did not understand the provided example the way you did :/

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to fetch all the rows from the database, so you can compare the current element with the next one. If `$current['Creation_date_M']` is different from `$next['Creation_date_M']`, then set a `last-day-of-month` class to the current `tr`.

But, since you are fetching one item at a time, and don't know what is comming next, you can store `$current['Creation_date_M']` in a variable as `$previousMonth` and compare with the next element in the next iteration. Using the same logic as above, if `$current['Creation_date_M']` is different from `$previousMonth`, then set a `first-day-of-month` class to the current `tr`. Note that you are styling the first day of the month instead of the last.

Example can be seen in this PHP sandbox: https://onlinephp.io/c/b6b5a

Your code would look something like this:

```php
<?php
  $query = '
    SELECT
      Project_ID,
      Creation_date,
      DATE_FORMAT(Creation_date, "%m") Creation_date_M,
      Project_name
    FROM Projects
    ORDER BY Creation_date DESC
  ';
  $result = $conn->query($query);
?>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Creation Date</th>
      <th>Project name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <?php
      // create a variable to store the previous month to compare with current one
      $previousMonth = null;
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):
        $month = $row['Creation_date_M'];
        if (!$previousMonth) $previousMonth = $month; 

        // if there is a change of month, define the class to be set
        if ($month != $previousMonth) {
          $previousMonth = $month;
          $trClass = "first-day-of-month";
        } else {
          $trClass = "";
        } 
    ?>
      <tr class="<?= $trClass ?>">
        <td><?= $row['Creation_date_full']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['Project_name']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: oh yeah! I think you just solve my problem, I saw your PHP sandbox, that's what I'm trying to do basicaly thank you so much, I will start with that!